# Multi computer cron

Tags: ssh, files, cron

I have many computers and I ssh between them.

I have a single cron file, which I manually type after into each computer.
And when I change this cron file, I have to manually ssh into each computer to update its cron accordingly.

Is there any way to have each computers cron, become a function of this file?

That way I could just have a single file, which gets synced between the computers and thus, updating the cron in each.

Comment: Consider using something like Ansible, Puppet or Chef instead to manage such configuration. Ansible is probably the easiest to get started with.

Comment: Im looking at the long term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is assuming that you are concerned with the crontab of a particular user, `myuser`.

A cron job re-reading the cron schedules from a file (`crontab crontab.txt`) would be fairly easy to set up, but you could do that from `ssh` directly with

```bash
ssh myuser@remote crontab - <crontab.txt
```

where `crontab.txt` is stored locally.

This could be put into a loop:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

remotes=( remote1 remote2 remote3 )

for remote in "${remotes[@]}"
do
    ssh "myuser@$remote" crontab - <crontab.txt
done
```

---

The alternative way that I initially skipped over above, with a job that re-reads the crontab:

This would require a crontab with at least a job like this:

```
0 * * * * crontab "$HOME/crontab.txt"
```

This job re-reads the schedules from `crontab.txt` in your home directory on the hour every hour.  That file should always contain at least this job.  You may then add other jobs to the file (by syncing the file from elsewhere), which would be added to the user's active crontab on the hour.

Comment: Is there a single command which just prints a given file, as the cron?

Comment: @john-jones I'm not quite sure what you mean. `crontab -l` will output the current user's current crontab.

Comment: like, i have a file on my computer. i would really like this file to just become the cron of that given computer. is there i command i could type to make that happen?

Comment: @john-jones If you have a set of cron job schedules in a text file, `crontab.txt`, you can load them as the cronjobs for the current user using `crontab crontab.txt`.  This is what I use in my answer (with `crontab -`, the schedules are read from standard input).  I'm unsure what you mean by "the cron of that given computer".  Crontabs belong to individual users.  There are also one or several system crontabs, and they live in `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d/`.  Do you want to _replace_ every single crontab on the entire system, for all users, with some single crontab?

Comment: no the root cron. no, got it its sudo -u username crontab file_with_table.

Comment: thank u very much.